Locale DNS not resolving - timed out
After several hours of searching, unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve the following problem and hope someone can help me.
On the Server is Ubuntu 22.04 with docker, which provide multiple website-containers. Actually i get sporadically in syslogs Apr  2 10:39:32 vm1 dockerd[887]: time="2024-04-02T10:39:32.567669384Z" level=error msg="[resolver] failed to query external DNS server" client-addr="udp:127.0.0.1:57901" dns-server="udp:127.0.0.53:53" error="read udp 127.0.0.1:57901->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout" question=";domain.de.\tIN\t AAAA" spanID=f7a5101a1c0540080df traceID=5fc4ba54560e892a27a98b0566bc8c43194
The problem is that sometimes websites can't send emails, and websites take too long to load.
Another errorlog that i get:
> nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 104.18.32.7
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 172.64.155.249
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out

systemd-resolve/resolvectl contain no errors or warnings.
Adding the nameserver of google (8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4) to /etc/resolv.conf not helping.
It also occurs even when only Docker is running and no containers are active. I feel like the issue disappears when I stop Docker.
Here is an example that shows how it suddenly works when I stop Docker:
root@vm1:/opt# nslookup askubuntu.com
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
^C
root@vm1:/opt# systemctl stop docker
Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:
  docker.socket

root@vm1:/opt# nslookup askubuntu.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.18.37.100
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 172.64.150.156


From the data, you seem to be getting a DNS timeout looking for an AAAA record. An AAAA record is the answer to an IPv6 query. Make sure that you fully support IPv6 or disable IPv6 on each and every system.

You can resolve AAAA records over IPv4. There's no reason this should be associated with IPv6 by the looks of it. I would rather attempt disabling systemd resolver.

@vidario After applying the suggestions from the link, I still encounter the same error. Despite having switched the DNS server in the meantime, I now see the Google DNS in the logs.
Apr  2 23:08:05 vm1 dockerd[885]: time="2024-04-02T23:08:05.193380008Z" level=error msg="[resolver] failed to query external DNS server" client-addr="udp:172.30.0.32:37457" dns-server="udp:8.8.4.4:53" error="read udp 172.30.0.32:37457->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout" question=";api.wordpress.org.\tIN\t A" spanID=9e9143704375423ad2 traceID=499163938bf5645ed0c5baacb136e97c198
